# UIWebView can only work with PNGs instead of JPGs?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, png, jpeg

I'm displaying an html page in UIWebView like this:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
   pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

The html contains a reference to an image:

```
<img src="ScreenshotTop.jpg" alt="Screenshot Top Part" />
```

I couldn't get to display the JPG at all (even when setting the baseURL as some other questions/answers have suggested). However, when I changed the format of the graphic to PNG and referenced that file like this:

```
<img src="ScreenshotTop.png" alt="Screenshot Top Part" />
```

everything worked fine. Does this mean that UIWebView can properly display PNGs, but can't work with JPGs? Or is there something else going on?

(FWIW, I'm using XCode 4.1 and the iOS Simulator 4.3.2.)

Answer (score 1):

Dont think this has to do with `PNG` or `JPG` images. Using relative paths or `file:` paths to refer to images does not work with UIWebView. Instead you have to load the HTML into the view with the correct baseURL:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

You can then refer to your images like this:

```
<img src="myimage.png">
```

Or from within CSS like this:

```
background-image: url(loading.gif)
```

It’s important to note that images inside your application bundle are at the root of the bundle, even if you place them in an Images directory in your project.

Check [here](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development/loading-local-files-into-uiwebview/) for more.

Comment: That's what I thought, too. I just re-checked my code, and I don't do anything else than a call to requestWithURL:. If there is a .jpg referenced, it doesn't work, if there is a reference to a .png, it does. I'm still baffled ....

Comment: can you just do a clean build & test this scenario again. Maybe some old cached file causing some confusion?

Comment: No changes. I even deleted the app in the simulator and re-ran .. still the same (odd) behavior.